# Two div elements, one fixed and the other one is auto. How to fix?

Tags: html, css

I have total brain freeze and I would appreciate a helping hand how to fix it.

I have 2x div elements. Called left and right:

I want the right element to have a fixed width of 320px, and the left one should be auto. So when I shrink the browser window, only the left element should become smaller.

I can get it working if the left element is fixed, but not the right one.

**Working code for left:**

```
.left {width: 320px;float: left;background:#CCC;}
.right { margin-left: 320px; background:#FFFF00; }
```

**Not a working code for right:**

```
.left_two { margin-right: 320px; background:#FFFF00; }
.right_two {width: 320px;float: right;background:#CCC; }
```

But this is how I want it to behaive.

You can follow my code and project here: ( simply shrink the browser window )

http://www.adamskymotorkylare.se/project/new.php

Thanks Jack

Comment: Is it something like this http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/CtTN7/2/

Comment: thanks for your respond, yeah, kinda, but it should be with 2x div elements.

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/CtTN7/6/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `html` `structure` as **like this**

```
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="right">right</div>

<div class="right_two">right</div>
<div class="left_two">left</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/53vAS/)**

Comment: can u change your html

Comment: just did, with your js fiddle css

Comment: yes as like my fiddle if you change your html than your problem is solved .

Comment: oh, didn't see the change order of right_two and left_two, it's working, thanks! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Hi Please try the calc property of css

I am giving a wrough demo code

### html

```
 <section class="container">
             <div>
        <div id="ds">
            left div
        </div>
        <div  class="flRight width320">
            right div
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div>
        <div class="width320">
            left div
        </div>
        <div id="ds2">
            right div
        </div>
    </div>

    </section>
```

### css

```
.container > div > div{float:left;
 border:1px solid red;
}

.clear{clear:both;}

.flRight{float:right;}

.width320{width:320px;}

 #ds{width:calc(99% - 320px);}

#ds2{width:calc(99% - 320px);}
```

Note : Please look for more information on calc http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS table display properties:

```
<div style='display:table'>
  <div class='display:table-cell; width: 320px;'>
     Left Column
  </div>
  <div class='display:table-cell;'>
     Right Column
  </div>
</div>
```